# Sending email from c#

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to make support form from C#. But when I send an email I get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Syntax error in parameters or
>   arguments. The server response was: 5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "/f"
>   invalid, closing connection.'

Here is my code;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            string email = YourEmail_box.Text;
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(YourEmail_box.Text);
            mailMessage.To.Add(Globals.supportemail);
            mailMessage.Subject = "New Email from " + email.ToString() + " [Howling-Software]";
            mailMessage.Body = this.subjectbox.Text;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Globals.credical_user, Globals.credical_pass);
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The From address must match the login account.  GMAIL then check for three items 1) From Address 2) Credential Name 3) Credential Password.  All three must be consistent with the data in server.  GMAIL also has a limit on the number of items in the send box.  So GMAIL may reject email if send box is too large.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution, and a bit cleaner solution :)

```
var message = new MailMessage(FromEmailAdress, ToEmailAdress);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = message;

using (SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
{
    mailer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmailAdress, password);
    mailer.EnableSsl = true;
    mailer.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.'`
I got this error

Comment: I just tried it again, still working. Could you upload your code to github, or show me how did you tried?